# Prove/disprove: $\exists y \in \mathcal N:\forall x\in \mathcal N, \exists \lambda >0: -\lambda y \le x \le \lambda y $

Tags: inequality, convergence-divergence

Let $\mathcal N \subset \mathbb R^\infty$ be the set of null sequences. We say for $x,y \in \mathcal N $ that $x\le y$ if $x_i \le y_i \  \forall i\in \mathbb N$. I would like to prove or disprove the following statement:
There is a $y \in \mathcal N$ such that for all $x \in \mathcal N$ and a $\lambda >0$
$$-\lambda y \le x \le \lambda y.$$

I feel like this should be provable:

Let $\lambda :=\sup_{n}x_n \ge 0$. This supremum does exist since we have a convergence sequence and is bigger or equal to zero since it is a null sequence. From there I cannot figure it out.

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: What does zero sequences mean?

Comment: A sequence that converges to zero, it is also known as null sequence.

Comment: Who uses "zero sequence" to mean this?? It's terrible terminology.

Comment: @BrianO Sorry for the confusion. I changed it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No such $y$  exists. Your inequality says that $M\equiv \sup_{y_n \neq 0} |\frac {x_n} {y_n} |<\infty$.   If $y_n=0$ for all $n$ sufficiently large then  the same must be true for all $x$ (by  the given inequalities) which is obviously false. If $y_n \neq 0$ for infinitely many $n$ we can choose $x$ with $|x_n| >M|y_n|$ for some $n$ with $y_n \neq 0$ violating the definition of $M$. (Make $x_k=0$ for all other $k$ so that $x$ becomes a  zero sequence).

Comment: @GEdgar Thanks. I have corrected the answer.

Comment: @geetha290krm Thank you for your answer! I got it now.